# How to make a multicolumn enumerated list where each column begins with the same number?

Tags: latex

I am trying to write an unofficial proof  with commentary in my one of my math courses, and I would like to be able to organize it like so:

[Column 1 | Column 2]

1. Statement | 1. Justification
2. Statement | 2. Justification
3. Statement | 3. Justification

I don't actually want any vertical rules between columns, I was just hard pressed to make two different columns in the text box. It is purely used as organization in my example.

That isn't exactly how I want it to look, but I hope it gets the idea across. I want two columns split evenly down the center of the page, both enumerated with the same number, and both aligned (so if necessary, my justification can run on for two or three lines without misaligning everything. That is, the first line of statement *n* must match with the first line of justification *n*).

Answer (score 0):

As a quick hack, I would use a tabular. If you need something more sophisticated, have a look at packages like `paracol`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{foo}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}p{.48\linewidth}p{.48\linewidth}@{}}
  \addtocounter{foo}{1}\thefoo. Statement & \thefoo. Justification\\ 
  \addtocounter{foo}{1}\thefoo. Statement & \thefoo. Justification\\ 
  \addtocounter{foo}{1}\thefoo. Statement & \thefoo. Justification\\ 
\end{tabular}%

\end{document}
```